# How to parse "にある" in this case?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> 体は睡眠状態にある。

On this [site](http://selftaughtjapanese.com/2015/07/27/expressing-state-in-japanese-with-ni-aru-and-ni-natte-iru/), it's explained that "you can think of this sentence as meaning the body is existing in the 睡眠 (sleep) state." and thus the sentence means "The body is in a state of sleep."

The problem is that for this sentence it doesn't work because shouldn't it be いる instead of ある?

> 両者は不可分の関係にある。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

デジタル大辞泉 distinguishes those two meanings of ある:

> #### [ある](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/7643/meaning/m0u/)
>
> １ 事物が**存在する**。「庭には池が―・る」「重大な欠陥が―・る」
>
> ３ ある事柄がはっきり**認められる**。また、ある**状態に置かれている**と認められる。「非は先方に―・る」「土地は高値安定の傾向に―・る」「大国の影響下に―・る」

So even though the third definition may be understood along the lines of "exist", they are different, and the rule regarding "いる/ある for existence in a physical place" does not apply.

Similar examples:

- 彼は絶体絶命の状況にある。 (いる is acceptable too)
- 2人はライバル関係にある。
- 彼はリスクを好む傾向にある。
- 彼は王の支配下にある。
- 2人は戦う宿命にある。
- 彼は社長という立場にある。 (いる is fine too)
- 彼はまだ初心者の段階にある。 (いる is fine too)

These ～にある are interchangeable with either ～が認められる ("shows some trait") or ～に置かれている ("placed in some situation").