# に particle used with noun

Tags: particle-に

ユキは空気を読まない傾向**に**あるからな

Why is に used above rather then が? I'd thought that when に is used with a noun (in this case 傾向), it indicates something is in the noun (in this case, something is in 傾向), which doesn't make sense

Second example:
私が勝つ**に**決まってるけどな

Why is に used instead of が. To me, に sounds like "decided in victory", which doesn't makes sense

Comment: 私の勝つ and んけど doesn't seem to make sense. Can you double check if you have correctly transcribed?

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth Yea, my bad, there isn't a ん, I will edit the question

Comment: What about 私の勝つ? It shouldn't be の.

Comment: @naruto he said that it was about nouns so I assumed that it is meant to be 勝ち since 私勝つに決まっている doesn't have a noun with に.

Comment: @naruto Ah my bad. It's supposed to be が instead of の. Edited

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57302/38770

Answer (score 1):

> ユキは空気を読まない傾向にあるからな
>
> Why is に used above rather then が? I'd thought that when に is used with a noun (in this case 傾向), it indicates something is in the noun (in this case, something is in 傾向), which doesn't make sense

Yes it does make sense, it's about positioning them within the "trend" towards being out of the loop.

> Second example: 私の勝つに決まっているけどな
>
> Why is に used instead of が. To me, に sounds like "decided in victory", which doesn't makes sense

Perhaps you already noticed, since you asked about nouns, but is probably 私の勝**ち** not 勝**つ** there. にきまっている is a set phrase which you can just learn, it means "no doubt" or "it is certain".

Comment: "it's about positioning *them* within the "trend" → If that were the case, shouldn't the verb be いる instead of ある?